# iOS Trim Square Image to make rounded app like in app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm grabbing app images from the iTunes affiliate program. Unfortunately Apple provides a square .jpg image which does not have the smooth rounded edges.  How can I programmatically take the provided image and round the edges?

The only way I can think of how to do this is set the image as the background of a view, and then round the layer borders until it cuts off what I don't want to see.  Is this a good approach?

Comment: I follow the same approach in my own apps. I think it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with that approach, I was going to suggest the same thing.